# Sort Parent by Child MAX in Django Model relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I don't know how to best explain my actual issue so here's something completely analogous. Auction listings and their bids.

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Bid(models.Model):
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Auction, related_name="bids")
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I want a list of auctions, ordered by the highest bid. I have a feeling this is going to have something to do with an aggregative Max, but can I go on to order by that aggregate value?

I have a feeling this is going to be really simple but I haven't really ever got into the aggregate stuff yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(Auction.objects.annotate(highest_bid=models.Max('bids__amount'))
                .order_by('-highest_bid'))
```

- [Aggregation cheat sheet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)

Comment: I *told* you it would be simple. Thanks Pavel. Seems to work well.